# Button can´t be moved from the top left corner when using drawerLayout in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

im new to android studio and im having torouble understanding views and layouts, the this is, im using a drawerLayout to add a toolbar, but when I added it, my button jumped to the topleft corner and I cant move it from there.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainScreen"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="313dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="798dp"
            android:text="Log Out"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/appBarLayout"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.003"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is my code

[image: And this is my design tab]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the margins from the button.
The design view in Android Studio can be helpful to get a layout started, but you almost always have go go in and manually adjust each element.